Algorithm to convert old map sheet number and grid refs to lat and long - Irish Ordnance Survey 1/2 inch maps
I have a list of 80 locations from an ecological survey in the early 1980s, and they are referenced by sheet number followed by 6 figure grid reference.
The sheet numbers are of the Irish Ordnance Survey 1/2 inch to the mile series.
How can I convert these references to latitude and longitude?
The references appear like this 16.123456 - sheet number 16, grid ref 123 easting, 456 northing.
I have a similar listing for the 1:50,000 discovery series, for which the sheet letter is given, and then the 6 figure grid reference - U.098765.
I need to convert both of these. Any ideas. I suspect the later series is less problematical. The earlier series had overlapping sheets

Latter series is probably this: http://simonstewart.ie/position/irishgrid.htm (just one reference).

For the first. I found a 1969 map just to confirm...you'll somehow have to find an index/polygons/corner coords of the maps. Each numbered sheet could include multiple letters. The 1969 map, number 20, in the indicia gives examples of Q and V locations.

A very simple search of the internet returned this site that will help you with the sites that start with a letter. I am unfamiliar with the sheet starting with a number, so maybe a deeper dive into the internet?

@Hornbydd - I used a very simple search on the internet and found that site, and it does as you say. But I am looking for an algorithm, or simple process, to convert these grid refs (Q 123 456) to lat long. I have very many of them and it would take a long time and subject to error if I input them through the webpage you have indicated.

@mkennedy that site at simonstewart.ie is ideal, thanks. I can work it out from that for the later grid refs. The earlier ones are a different matter. What's indicia?

You could always use the Irish geodetic service they have an app that might convert in batch?

@RobinDavidLewando I may have the name wrong (actually not a cartographer!), the text and diagrams around the edge of a map. example

The first system appears to have overlapping sheets (if they are the same half-inch maps as geo-referenced here). Following on from @mkennedy's comment an algorithmic approach may require the coordinate reference system to be defined for each paper map, and then the appropriate crs be used for each coordinate to convert to latitude/longitude. A manual alternative: look up the paper map and manually re-read as latitude/longitude from the margins.
The second system e.g. U098765 is an "Irish grid reference". These are based on the Irish Grid crs, now EPSG code 29903. There are several online converters and some can convert multiple coordinates at a time so it should not be necessary to implement your own algorithm.
If you want to use R, the R package igr can convert a list of arbitrary Irish grid references into Irish Grid or any other crs including WGS 84 for Latitude/Longitude. See the examples for the function st_igr_as_sf().

@jkennedyie The principle behind the coding should be simple enough, when I get time. Having got hold of a set of the half inch sheets I find that despite being in 'imperial' scale, they are still based on the metric Irish Grid.
The SW corner of each sheet has the coordinates given in red. These are six figures, and the first number in the six figures refers to the Irish Grid - hundreds of km north or east. If the coordinate given is five figures, then the coordinate should be prefixed with a 0.
Using the knowledge that the IG is 500km north and 500km east, starting at 0,0, the 100 km square lettered between 400 and 500 N and 0 and 100 E is A, between 400 and 500 N and 100 and 200 E is B and between 300 and 400 N and 0 and 100 east is F. So from this we can work out the IG squares ABCDE along the top row etc., to VWXYZ along the bottom.
The Killarney sheet (21, see the attachment from @mkennedy) gives the coordinates of 67733 N and 75877 E at the SW corner - that is 067733, 075877. Thus this sheet overlaps parts of four IG squares - from V in the SW, across east into W, and into Q and R above.
Given a coordinate like, for example, 21.952787, 952 and 787 are both in the SW most sheet, i.e. V, and thus translates to V952787
Similarly, 21.005935 translates to W005935.
The IG gridlines on the map are distances from the origin, E and N, but leaving out the hundreds number. The next gridline after 90 is thus 00, and the grid letter tells you which hundreds number to use.
So reverting these two examples back to IG full number system, V952787 is thus 09520787, and W005935 is 10050935. These represent 95.2km E and 78.7 km N, and 100.5km E and 93.5km N respectively, from the origin of the IG.
